# Incremental indexing for semantic search

Tags: indexing, rdf, semantic-web, triplestore

I wonder if there are some standards or best practices, in performing an incremental indexation of a triple store for semantic search purpose.

Indeed to support semantic search one usually use solr or elasticsearch where resource are indexed according to some specific SPARQL query. While one can re-index its entire resources set once a day for instance, it is not that desirable. Hence comes the need to perform it incrementally. However that requires somehow to track changes, with the ultimate goat to be able to keep on indexing or deleting whatever has changed only.

For instance to only index what has change, the SPARQL query should include some timestamp filter somehow.

If anyone has some suggestions, or experience on performing it, that he would like to share this would be well apreciated

So far I am being somewhat inspired by EEA ElasticSearch RDF River Plugin. I'm also looking at the ontology Changeset Ontology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to get something involved in the transaction lifecycle. Then you're able to see the changes to the database which will give you the graph that needs to be indexed.

But don't dismiss doing a full re-index on a periodic schedule, such as nightly. Unless your requirement is that full-text searches *must* always be against the most recent data *and* your data changes quickly, a full re-index on a regular basis will work just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "The easiest way to accomplish this would be to get something involved in the transaction lifecycle. Then you're able to see the changes to the database which will give you the graph that needs to be indexed."

Comment: So basically, the idea would to use an ontology like change set and record myself every changes ? Any time I do an operation in my database, i have to add the corresponding changeSet operation? Is that correct ?

Comment: Have you considered using a database that does full-text indexing?

Comment: Yes But then i won't have all the goodies of ElasticSearch or Solr e.g. Hints highlighting and so on... Beside i think/beleive that controlling exactly what you want to index is much better. Usually those database simply index all Literals. You still have to do a sparql query to get want you want. I presume that this is slightly, slower than executing your query in solr.

Comment: I was thinking about Stardog, which is the one I use. I think Graph DB has something a bit much better for that, they have connector for Solr or ElasticSearch, and handle the synchronization that i am talking about. But this is a deep integration with there system. I would like to reproduce that but from the outside.

Comment: If you're going to reproduce that functionality from the outside, then I would suggest you try what I said; get into the transaction lifecycle and use the changeset for the transaction as the payload of what needs to be incrementally indexed. If you cannot extend the database, it would be pretty easy to achieve that externally via a decorator around the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I think I understand overall what you mean. Although I believe you are one step ahead of me when it come the details of db. I have no idea of what an API for the transaction life-cycle look like.never went that deep in db. I don't think indeed stardog would allow to do that. It is not open source at all.

Comment: I will investigate how to do that with a decorator. Just to make sure that we are in alignment, with a decorator, I will have to Supply the changeset myself ? I don't think generating a changeset generically is that easy to implement, so it has to be somewhat supplied each time an update is done?

Comment: no, the user is going to provide the changeset via the connection to the database; that's what you'd decorate.  Then you'll have a set of RDF graphs  that are to be added and/or deleted from the database which gives you the basis of the information that needs to be incrementally indexed

Comment: @MaatDeamon I have only half-read your requirements and this discussion, but it might be worth having a look at the Sesame LuceneSail, which allows integration with Lucene, Solr, or ElasticSearch, and supports both embedded indexing as well as connecting to a remote indexing server.